# How to open only one dropdown at a time in shopify footer menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu, shopify

My client wants his Shopify website to open only one dropdown to open at a time and when he clicks on another menu dropdown the other should close. How to make it possible in Shopify?

Answer (score 1):

Go to theme.liquid and open the footer section and paste these footer menu code
on your footer section file.

```
<nav>
                        <ul class="my-nav">
                          {% for link in linklists[section.settings.footer_link_list].links %}
                          {% if link.links != blank %}
                          <li>
                            <details class="dropdown">
                              <summary>{{ link.title }}</summary>
                              <ul>
                                {% for child_link in link.links %}  
                                <li><a href= "{{ child_link.url }}">{{ child_link.title }}</a>
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                              </ul>
                            </details>
                          </li>
                          {% else %}
                          <li class="site-nav__item">
                            <a 
                               mega="{{ link.title | escape }}"
                               href="{{ link.url }}"
                               class="site-nav__link nav-link"
                               data-meganav-type="child">
                              {{ link.title | escape }}
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                      </nav>
<script>
                        var nav = document.querySelector('.my-nav');
nav.addEventListener('toggle', function (event) {
    
    // Only run if the dropdown is open
    if (!event.target.open) return;

    // Get all other open dropdowns and close them
    var dropdowns = nav.querySelectorAll('.dropdown[open]');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(dropdowns, function (dropdown) {
        if (dropdown === event.target) return;
        dropdown.removeAttribute('open');
    });

}, true);
                      </script>
```